# 2D Animation Blending

Tags: animation, interpolation, blending

I have been researching on 2D Animation Blending technique similar to what Unity 4.3 has.
I know how Animation blending in 3D works but I have no idea how it works in 2D. How does 2D Animation Blending work?

Thank You.

Comment: The same, but with one less dimension. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am wondering how 2D Blending would work because we don't have an actual framework which will control the movement as in 3D. All we have is sprites. Also, is it possible to use a 3D model but project it on a 2D plane? Is it efficient.
Can you suggest any good articles about the same topic?

Comment: 3D graphics is already all about projecting a 3D model onto a 2D plane. You could play with the [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/) trial to get a feel for what's possible.

Comment: Alright. I will try that. Thank you for the guidance. Appreciate it!